# How to fit 25 divs inside one div when I have more than 25 child divs?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a parent div and it's size is 100px X 100px and I have to add child divs inside it , where each child div is 20px X 20px, so If I have 50 child div , I want to show only the first 25 div. and If one div id hidden (faded out for example) the 25 divs are shifted to show always only 25 div.

How can I make that using CSS only. If is not possible in CSS only, we may use jquery to do that.

### EDIT: More details:

I have tried !! this is problem . The parent div accommodates only 25s I have more than 25, they overflow the parent div . I want to show only 25 and the rest to be not appeared . but if one div it disappeared , its neighbor will fill its place , so always I have 25 only(no more or less)

Comment: If you have said something, may I accept you answer rather offending !!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give each of your child divs the style

```
display: inline-block;
width: 20px; /* not 25, that's too big to fit 5 into 100px (100 / 25 == 4) */
height: 20px;
```

Which will make them not have line-breaks after them, then give the parent div the style

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Which will make any divs that go outside the parent divs space not show up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief example that utilizes jquery for hiding the inner elements: http://jsfiddle.net/ERaP3/

Note, that you will need to either refresh the page or add another toggle to show the previously hidden elements.